# Non uniform output when serializing lists in com.thoughtworks.xstream Jettison JSON convertor

Tags: json, xstream, jettison

I'm having a real issue with the Java Jettison JSON package.
For some reason, I'm getting a different representation for lists that are of length 1 and lists of length > 1.

In the next example you can see I'm creating two List - one of length 1 (list1) and one of length 2 (list2):

```
@Test
public void test() throws JsonParseException {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("1");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("1");
    list2.add("2");

    XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
    xstream.setMode(XStream.XPATH_ABSOLUTE_REFERENCES);

    String list1String = xstream.toXML(l1);
    String list2String = xstream.toXML(l2);

}
```

What I get back is:

```
list1 = {"list":[{"string":**1**}]},
list2 = {"list":[{"string":**[1,2]**}]}.
```

What I would want to get back is:

```
list1 = {"list":[{"string":**[1]**}]},
list2 = {"list":[{"string":**[1,2]**}]}
```

Why is this happening? It's driving the iPhone JSON parser crazy (of course this is a scaled down version of the problem).

I've seen a lot of discussions saying to ditch Jettison and to work with Jackson, but that's not an option for me now.

Thanks!